# How do you adjust Sybase optimizer settings in Java at the session level?

Tags: java, performance, sybase, database-performance, sap-ase

Per Sybase, you can adjust optimizer settings at the session level as such:

```
set plan optgoal allrows_dss
```

But what is the syntax I would use to include this in a connection string using Java's DriverManager.getConnection?  Right now I do something like this:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sybase:Tds:myservername:myportnum/myDBname", user, password);
```

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so eventually figured it out, sharing for anyone who wants to know in the future.  Don't know if this is the right or best way, but it works:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, user, password);
Statement s = conn.createStatement().executeUpdate(" set plan optgoal allrows_oltp ");
ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(" select @@optgoal ");
rs.next();
System.out.println("Session-level optimizer set to: " + rs.getString(1));
```